# How would you explain these mistakes to an adult language learner?

Tags: errors

what is the mistake in "I Have visited washington two years ago"?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You don't need "have".

Comment: This question may be suitable for English Language Learners, but not EL&U.

Comment: Not suitable for any site without showing minimum research, sorry to say. Please see the answer posted to this question [“have found” vs. “found”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161887/have-found-vs-found/161891#161891)

Comment: Before voting to migrate this question, please [see here first](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11075/please-dont-migrate-obviously-off-topic-questions-to-ell-it-just-makes-things).